# View images from google drive folder in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-drive-api

I want to display a folder of images in my flutter app like a grid of images.
All answers was about view single image not folder of images
if any one have same issue help please
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this plugin [google_drive_client](https://pub.dev/packages/google_drive_client).